# wifi conections

Tags: сеть, wifi

Как узнать кто пытался подключиться к моему роутеру и неправильно ввел пароль и что ввел именно?

Answer (score 1):

Что именно он ввел узнать не получится потому как wpa не передает пароль напрямую, а использует 4х-этапный обмен ключами.

Какой мак пытался подключиться иногда можно найти в логах. Тут больше зависит от программного обеспечения роутера.